# JSON keys for a movie title have different names

Tags: javascript, api

Trying to fetch data from TMDb (The movie database), when I iterate through an array of objects to get the movie titles, some objects have the key name for movie name as `original_title`, but in other objects the movie name is `original_name`. So when I iterate through the objects some of the movie titles just come back as undefined.

```
const APIKey = <api_key>;
const APIUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=<api_key>&page=1"
const imagePath = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"

getTrendingMovieData(APIUrl);
async function getTrendingMovieData(url) {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const data = await resp.json();
    console.log(data.results);
    showTrendingMovies(data.results);
};

function showTrendingMovies(movies) {
movies.forEach(movie => {
    trending = document.createElement("div");
    trending.classList.add('movie');
    const { id, original_title, release_date } = movie;
    trending.innerHTML = `
    <img src="${imagePath + movie.poster_path}" alt="${id}">
    <div class="movie-info">
        <p id="title">${original_title}</p>
        <div class="date-genre">
            <p>${release_date}<span>Thriller</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="review">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-star" id="star"></i><p>7.4 <span>(85,000)</span></p>
        </div>
    </div> 
    `;
    document.getElementById("trending-movies").appendChild(trending);
    });
};
```

When I try with `original_title` it works except the objects that have key `original_name` just returns undefined. Whereas if I try with `original_name` I get an

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: original_name is not defined.

Comment: If you look at the data `title` appears to be associated with `media_type: 'movie'` and `name` is associated with `media_type: 'tv'`. I don't know how consistent that is but it might be worth checking the rest of the data to see if that's a condition you can check to decide which to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
const { id, original_title, original_name, release_date } = movie;
trending.innerHTML = `
<img src="${imagePath + movie.poster_path}" alt="${id}">
<div class="movie-info">
    <p id="title">${original_title ?? original_name}</p>
    <div class="date-genre">
        <p>${release_date}<span>Thriller</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-star" id="star"></i><p>7.4 <span>(85,000)</span></p>
    </div>
</div> 
`;
```

it will simply use original_name if the original_title is undefined

Comment: It's better now to use the null coalescing operator, `??` rather than the logical OR operator `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Because some objects have the `key` name for the movie name as `original_title`, and for other objects, the movie name is `original_name`.

You need to iterate through your objects and change the `original_title` to `original_name` or `original_name` become `original-title`.

#### Example

```js
const movies = [
  { title: 'Dark Land' },
  { title: 'Dark Land' },
  { name: 'Dark Land' },
];

const changedKeys = movies.map((movie) => {
  const { title, ...otherProps } = movie;
  const newMovieStruct = { name: title, ...otherProps };
  return newMovieStruct;
});
console.log(changedKeys);
```